# system problem! ubuntu 12.4

Tags: system

when I was upgrading to ubuntu 12.4 I had to leave and accidentally turned off the laptop in half update. When lit it not entered the system, it put the screen in black and looked just the mouse. I had to install ubuntu 12.4 from a dvd drive apart, when I installed told me that was already installed, it saids that if you wanted to install ubuntu 12.4 with ubuntu 12.4 and I did it, but now I have two ubuntu 12.4 and also can not find my files . What I can do?

Answer (score 0):

To get your files you could try to start **Disk Utility** and then search the drives and partitions with that tool. You should be able to mount the partitions and open them with Nautilus (file manager) by clicking onto the path shown after "Mount Point":

[image: disk utility]

I don't know if you can rescue your old system with all the custom settings. Possibly you should do a complete reinstall and use the full harddisk after you got your files.